# Adding an airport extreme base station so I can connect an aftermarket backup disk to the network to be used by Time Machine.

Tags: network

We have our home network connected through an ATT uverse router.  I want to add an airport extreme base station so I can connect an aftermarket backup disk to the network to be used by Time Machine. What is the best way to hook up the airport extreme so it is always available to Time Machine?

Comment: For reference - this is a newly supported feature in the 6th generation Airport Extreme Base Stations (the "Tower" model) - so, be sure you do get this model.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand uverse needs their router used instead of any other. So I think you will have to put the AEBS into bridge mode and not have it working as a router. It should still serve up the hard drive as a time capsule, it just won't be doing the DHCP or DNS work for your network. The uverse router will be fulfilling that role.